# Spring Boot Error: Failed to refresh live data from process 90196

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I am trying to create a RESTful website using Spring Tool Suite. I am getting the error:

```
"Failed to refresh live data from process 90196 - com.example.demo.DemoApplication after retries: 10."
```

I am unsure why I am getting this error. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

[image: error image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I can explain that... :-) This is part of this feature of the tooling:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Live-Application-Information

The aim of this feature is to provide live information from a running Spring application and merge that information with the source code of your workspace, so that you get live information in-place right within your editor.

This information that the IDE uses is provided by the Spring Boot actuators. In order to make this as automatic and easy to use as possible, the IDE automatically tries to connect to a running Spring process and tries to identify that live information. This might not work for various reasons (like the process is not responding, the Spring app doesn't have the actuators on the classpath, JMX connection isn't working, whatever). After trying to get the data for a specific process 10 times, the tooling gives up (assuming there is no live data to extract from the process) and shows the above message.

You can disable this "automatically try to connect to a running process" in the `Preferences -> Language Servers -> Spring Language Server -> Spring Boot Language Server -> Spring Boot Java` and disable `Live Information - Automatic Process Tracking Enabled`. If you want to display that live information nevertheless, you can connect to a running process manually, too (using the quick access or the action the boot dashboard views menu). In that case, take care to add the actuators to the Spring Boot project before starting up the app.

Hope that helps!